# Tabulator 5.4, search in multiple columns

Tags: javascript, tabulator

How to perform a search in multiple columns at the same time?

According to the Tabulator 5.4 documentation, code below should do the job, but it doesn't.

```
let input = document.querySelector('#searchField');
input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    tabulator.setFilter([
        {field:"col_a", type:"like", value:input.value},
        {field:"col_b", type:"like", value:input.value}
    ]);
    if (input.value == " ") {
        tabulator.clearFilter();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code implements an AND condition. For OR you just need to add [ ] to the setFilter description

```
let input = document.querySelector('#searchField');
input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    if (input.value == "") {
        tabulator.clearFilter();
    }
    else {
        tabulator.setFilter([[
        {field:"col_a", type:"like", value:input.value},
        {field:"col_b", type:"like", value:input.value}
        ]]);
    }
});
```